# Stochastic epidemic models with branching process

Tags: survival, epidemiology, disease, branching

I am looking for an academic survey article that uses branching process in stochastic epidemic models. There are journal articles in epidemic and bio statistics that deal with specific transmittable diseases.

Do you know a comprehensive survey article dealing with statistical methods building on branching process? A textbook recommendation would be also helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great textbook is the classical [branching processes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486434745).

If you are not versed in basic stochastic processes, I suggest you also consider to take a look at [Ross](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471120626). This is a great book with a section that deals with branching processes.